# Diode losses in switching power supply

Tags: switching-losses

I couldn't find a simple approx formula for calculating diode reverse recovery losses!
I am not doing any rocket science, so I just need an approx formula (not worried much about temperature effects and small variation in parameters). I have been searching in Google for answer, most of answer refer to an litterateur, which has detailed calculation including "n" number of variables. Please suggest a basic formula for approximating diode recovery losses.

Comment: @JYELTON: Thanks for improving it. I am not good at grammar and sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The following information is taken from the slides for Coursera's Introduction to Power Electronics class, which is based on ECEN5797 at the University of Colorado Boulder.

You will need to know the following parameters, which come from your design and the diode datasheet:

\$t_{r}\$: Diode reverse recovery time (typically tens of nanoseconds)

\$Q_{r}\$: Reverse recovery charge (not sure what's typical -- hundreds of nanocoulombs?)

\$I_L\$: Average inductor current

\$V_{DR}\$: Diode reverse voltage -- equal to the input voltage \$V_g\$ (for a buck converter) or the output voltage \$V\$ (for a boost converter)

\$T_S\$: The switching period

Assume that the diode changes at the end of the reverse recovery transient. This is a pessimistic assumption. These graphs show the transistor and diode waveforms for a buck converter:

[image: Transistor and diode waveforms for reverse recovery]

Using this assumption, the reverse recovery power loss can be approximated as:

### $$V_{DR}(\frac{t_r I_L}{T_S} + \frac{Q_r}{T_S})$$

Answer (score 0):

From Microship's Web Seminar on DC-DC converter design example, Buck converter example. Their particular application example is a 2A converter ouput.

***Buck Converter Diode Selection***

Estimate Diode Current:
ID = (1-D) · ILOAD

ID = (1.0- 0.416) · 2A = 1.17 A

Where D = Duty cycle

Max Diode Reverse Voltage = 12V

Select Schottky rectifier:
A 1N5820, 20V, 3 A Schottky meets requirements

Power Dissipation: VF · ID = 0.47 Watts

**Here is their reasoning:**
*The diode’s average current is equal to the load current times the portion of
time the diode is conducting.
The time the diode is on is: (1 – duty cycle)
The maximum reverse voltage on the diode is Vin which is 12 volts in this
example.
The current and voltage ratings are low enough that a small schottky diode
can be used for this application.
By using a schottky diode, switching losses are negligible.
The forward voltage drop for the selected diode is about 0.4 volts at the peak
current of 2.0 amps.
The estimated diode power dissipation is 0.47 watts.*

[source for microchip's web seminar PDF of the presentation slides](http://simonthenerd.com/files/smps/SMPSBuckDesign_031809.pdf)

I hope this is a reasonably informative document, I found it very helpful during my design process. I put the formulas into excel spreadsheets and I now have some handy design documents! The web seminar goes through input and output capacitor selection, and MOSFET selection, among other things. There are also very good app notes from Texas Instruments for design of, and selection of, components used in DC-DC Conversion circuits. They almost always have accompanying formulas and reasons for their choices which you can learn from.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But this is Conduction loss calculation. Where as i am looking for Diode Reverse recovery loss approx. formula.

Comment: @CHETANBHUSANUR oh, my bad. sorry mate! I'll leave the answer here in case it's interesting to anyone.